# what is boost::spirit::standard encoding?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

There are several `Character Encoding Namespace` in boost spirit, including:

```
boost::spirit::qi::ascii
boost::spirit::qi::iso8859_1
boost::spirit::qi::standard
boost::spirit::qi::standard_wide
boost::spirit::qi::unicode
```

I know ascii and iso8859_1 and unicode, but I don't know what are `standard` and `standard_wide`.

I don't know what exactly boost::spirit::qi::unicode is neither, UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32? It should be one of the three, not all.

I also noticed the `standard` can match characters encoded as UTF-8.

But I can't find any detail about these encoding spaces, what do they mean exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Standard uses the standard library character classifications. So, it matches the behaviour from [`<cctype>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) which uses the system locale.

In effect it is less strict than `qi::ascii` which supports only 7-bit characters.

`qi::standard` supports 8-bit chars, where the meaning of the additional values depends on the system's locale.

---

To the side question: unicode uses 32-bit characters with code points in the range 0x00 to 0x10FFFF